# ImageButton detect click even on transparent pixels

Tags: android, layout, imagebutton

with ImageButton , I use android:background="@null" and an image with transparent pixels and text on it

the problem is sometimes , click are not detected. I suppose this is related to transaprent pixels, because if I remove android:background="@null" I dont have any problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try using:

```
android:background="#00000000"
```

Here, the 1st 2 zeros indicates that your background should be transparent (ARGB format), where A is the alpha (transparency)

Answer (score 0):

For a transparent background I use:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```